# What does Minimum Slot Aperature mean?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Exploring some fab houses and I came across this statement from https://www.viapart.com/PCB/Explain

"Minimum slot aperture 
Mechanical drill 0.6mm The tolerance of groove aperture is±0.1mm"

Does this mean that the smallest hole they can make is ~24mils with an annular ring of ~4mils ? If not, what does Minimum Slot Aperature mean ?

How could one extract annular ring size from their description ?

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret this as the smallest slot they can make is the equivalent of a 0.6mm hole, dragged along the line of the slot. As in, the smallest tool they'll use for a slot is their 0.6mm drill, and they're putting a 0.1mm tolerance on the width of that slot.

> Does this mean that the smallest hole they can make is ~24mils with an annular ring of ~4mils ?

Not necessarily. They may have smaller drill sizes available for vias and non-slot holes.

Comment: Updated question slightly with a link to the source of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they auto-translated the page.

I think the spec you are looking for is what they call "minimum pore size".
I'm guessing "pore" is a bad translation for what we would usually call a "hole". Then this spec is giving you the minimum drill diameter for round holes.

They have different specs for mechanical and laser drilled "pores", but both are smaller than 0.6 mm.

But if you really want to know what you are getting, you might consider using a shop that has better English communication skills, or ask your sales rep from this shop directly.